# Finding the binary tree height in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, binary-tree

So I have a task to create a binary tree using the following facts that define each node with its two child nodes:

```
node(root, a, b).
node(a, c, d).
node(b, z, y).
node(c, e, f).
node(d, x, w).
node(e, g, h).
node(z, v, u).
node(u, t, s).
node(t, r, q).
```

I want to define the rule height(RootNode, Height) to calculate the height of the binary tree that
starts at the RootNode. The height of a tree is the longest distance (number of nodes) from
the root node to the farthest away leaf node. A leaf node is a node that doesn’t have any
children. The height of a leaf node is 1.

The code I currently have is:

```
node(root, a, b).
node(a, c, d).
node(b, z, y).
node(c, e, f).
node(d, x, w).
node(e, g, h).
node(z, v, u).
node(u, t, s).
node(t, r, q).

height(nil, 0).
height(RootNode, Height):-
    node(RootNode, Left, Right),
    height(Left, LH),
    height(Right, RH),
    Height is max(LH, RH) + 1.
```

At the moment, I'm really stuck and would love to know what happens to this code when it runs, why I've done this incorrectly and where I should look to improve further? Appreciate any help.

Comment: what is `nil`? what is `f`? should it be `node(c, e, nil).` or `node(f, nil, nil).`?

Comment: also, you've included your facts twice. one time is enough, no need to repeat them. you can edit to remove the excess code.

Comment: These were the rules that were given to me, so it must be like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your base case requires that each leaf node exists in the database in the form `node(Leaf, nil, nil)` but according to your example leaf nodes are just nodes that appear as the second or third argument of a `node/3` fact but does not appear as the first argument of another `node/3` fact.

So you may fix your code by changing your base case:

instead of

```
height(nil, 0).
```

use

```
height(Leaf, 1):-
  \+node(Leaf, _, _).
```

(note that the base case has height 1 as per your description)

Test case:

```
?- height(root,A).
A = 6 ;
false.
```

You may also "join" both clauses in a single one:

```
height(RootNode, Height):-
    node(RootNode, Left, Right) *->
    (height(Left, LH),
    height(Right, RH),
    Height is max(LH, RH) + 1) ; Height = 1.
```

test run:

```
?- height(root,A).
A = 6.
```

Comment: why `*->` ? you allow for more than one node with the same identifier?

Comment: To allow using an unbound variable as the first argument to `height/2`

Comment: @WillNess: calling `height(Node, Height)` won't return leafs though in the "joined" procedure

Comment: Thank you for the answer, appreciate that. So, it was just my base case that wasn't correct? If so, does it read: The leaf node height is equal to 1 if the leaf node doesn't have any more leaf nodes?

Comment: @Tw1sssted: Yes, the base case was not correct. A leaf node is, by definition, a node which does not have children. So it would read: a node height is equal to 1 if the node does not have any children.

Comment: @gusbro Thank you very much for clearing this anomaly.